# How to fetch data from Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I just finished making my own basic REST Web Service by watching tutorials from youtube but the problem is all the Django REST Framework tutorials that I've seen only focuses on how to create REST API and I've never seen anyone explain how to integrate with it.

So now I just want to ask how I can fetch the data from it? I mean I can log in or Get the data or even insert data using Postman. But how can I do it using a Django Website?

For example, if I make another Django Website and I want to use the REST API that I made. How can I do it? If possible I also want to Register/Login using the REST Web Service that I created.

Note: I never tried any codes yet since I absolutely have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Basically, what you are looking for is how to consume RESTful API from Python as a client. You can consume it from browser which is purely using Javascript or any Javascript frameworks. You can also consume it from server side using Python http.client. So what you are after is HttpClient to consume RESTful API

Answer (score 0):

RESTFUL API's provides communication between two applications. DRF was developed on top of Django to do this. Working with Django you will use the urls to provide communication between the templates(front end) with viewsets hence no need of using REST API with django. With DRF urls provides end points for external applications to communicate with your backend like mobile apps, angular apps and react.
Get method is defined in the viewset which interprets the request defined in the url e.g

```
#Model
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
#Serializer
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
#Viewset
'''
For commonly perfomed operations you can use class based views to provide conformity in your APIs
'''
class StudentViewset(APIView)
    #Define here your get method
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        student = Student.objects.all()
        serializer = StudentSerializer(student)
        Response(serializer.data)
##URLS
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/students',StudentViewset.as_view())
]
```

To connect your front end to this page like in angular you will send a request like

```
  http.get('localhost:8000/api/student').subscribe
#Or using JQUERY YOU CAN SEND A REQUEST LIKE
   $.get('localhost:8000/api/student')
```